# Calling const member function in a non-const member function while both of them same function name

Tags: c++, function-qualifier

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void Bar()const
    {
        std::cout << "A::Bar() const\n";
    }

    void Bar()
    {
        std::cout << "A::func()\n";
        //call Bar()const in here
    }
};
```

I would like to know how i should call `Bar()const` member function in `Bar()` member function?

Comment: I'd guess you could do `const_cast<const MyClass*>(this)->Bar();` or use [std::add_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_cv) or [std::as_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const) or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the object to a `const` qualified version to call the `const` function.  That would look like

```
void Bar()
{
    std::cout << "A::func()\n";
    const_cast<const MyClass&>(*this).Bar(); // calls const version
}
```